# Unable to ping between two virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox, ping

I've two virtual machines in virtual box which I've configured with quagga. I'm trying to do a ping between them but I don't get response. Here are the zebra, ospf and bgp files:

Router 1:

```
!
hostname router1
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface eth0
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface eth1
 ip address 192.168.6.1/24
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface lo
!
ip forwarding
!
!
line vty
!
```

-

```
!
!
hostname ospfd
password zebra
log stdout
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 192.168.6.1
 redistribute connected
 redistribute bgp
 network 192.168.6.0/24 area 0.0.0.0
!
line vty
!
```

-

Router 2:

```
!
hostname router2
password zebra
enable password zebra
!
interface eth1
 ip address 192.168.5.1/24
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface eth2
 ip address 192.168.6.2/24
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
interface lo
!
ip forwarding
!
!
line vty
!
```

-

```
!
!
hostname ospfd
password zebra
log stdout
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 192.168.6.2
 redistribute connected
 redistribute bgp
 network 192.168.5.0/24 area 0.0.0.0
 network 192.168.6.0/24 area 0.0.0.0
!
line vty
!
```

-

```
!
hostname bgpd
password zebra
log stdout
!
router bgp 2000
 bgp router-id 192.168.6.2
 network 192.168.6.4/24
 network 192.168.5.0/24
 redistribute connected
 no synchronization
 redistribute ospf
 neighbor 192.168.6.1 remote-as 2000
 neighbor 192.168.5.2 remote-as 500
!
line vty
!
```

For now I'm just testing these two routers so bgp is not used because they are in the same AS.

When I try to ping from router 1 to router 2 I get nothing. When I try to ping from router 2 to router 1 I get "Destination Host Unreachable"

If I look at ifconfig the IP addresses are correct. Why I'm not able to ping?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please add option "multicast" to all interfaces in zebra.conf because OSPF use multicast, then restart both zebra and ospfd.